# Weighted Hardy space composition

Tags: complex-analysis, inner-products, hardy-spaces

Let $H^2(\omega)$ be the closure of the set of analytic on the unit circle $T$ polynomials, with respect to the scalar product
$$
\langle f, g\rangle_\omega = \oint_T f \bar{g} \omega \,\mathrm{d}z,
$$
where $\omega$ is a non-negative absolutely continuous non-constant weight on $T$.

Is it the case that $H^2(\omega)\subset H^2$ ? I feel that it's not, but can't construct a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Great first question!

Comment: Thanks, I think the answer involves orthogonal projection of  $z^0$ onto $z H^2$

Comment: You can directly any additional information into your answer.

Comment: Is $\hat{g}$ the point-wise conjugated function of $g$? Do you really mean only the closure of polynomials or do you mean trigonometric polynomials?

Comment: Yes, $\hat{g}$ is complex conjugate, so if \omega=const you get standard L^2 scalar product. By "polynomials" I mean polynomials in z, so you might equivalently say "complex trigonometric polynomials". Nothing else really makes sense in the context, does it?

Comment: Edited to use \bar{g} instead of \hat{g} to denote complex conjugation

Answer (score 1):

If $f = \sum_n c_n e^{2i\pi n x}$ is periodic and $L^2[0,1]$ then $|c_n|$ is bounded so that $F_k(z)= \sum_n c_n z^n e^{-\pi n^2/k^2}$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}^*$.

Moreover $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\|F_k(e^{2i\pi x})- f\|_{L^2[0,1]}^2 =\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_n |c_n|^2 (1-e^{-\pi  n^2/k^2})^2 = 0$$

$H^2$ is the subspace with $c_n = 0$ for $n < 0$, the entire functions are dense in it.

If I took this $e^{-\pi n^2/k^2}$ regulator it is because $$F_k(e^{2i\pi x}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty k e^{-\pi k^2 y^2} f(x-y)dy$$ so $F_k(e^{2i\pi x})$ is also an approximation of $f$ in every norm.

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite understand your answer. If $c_n=0$ for $n<0$, then $F_k\in H^2$, and so is its limit.

Comment: Yes, and, what is unclear to you ? Your weight $\omega$ doesn't change anything given that you meant $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_T f \bar{g} \omega \,\mathrm{d}|z|$.  In this context  $dz$ is a complex valued measure.

Comment: Then it is not a counterexample I am looking for, because it does not establish that there are some functions in $H^2(\omega)$ that are not in $H^2$

Comment: Because with the correct definitions there are not.

Comment: Well, what about a counterexample that I just posted?

Comment: Perhaps my notation is not entirely clear. I mean that when $\omega$ is constant, the scalar product becomes conventional Euclidean product in $L^2$.
The definition of $\pi$ is exactly the same as in literature, such as "Banach spaces of analytic functions" by Hoffman. Certainly, $\pi$ is in $H^2$, are you sure you read my answer carefully?

Comment: What means "the orthogonal projection of $1$ on $z H^2$" ? The $g(z)=\sum_{n \ge 1} c_nz^n$ minimizing $\int_0^1 |g(e^{2i \pi x})-1|^2 \omega(x)dx$ ? Then $g(z)$ is the limit of the  sequence of entire functions $g_k(z ) =\sum_{n \ge 1} c_nz^n e^{-n^2/k^2}$

Comment: Yes, it does mean that, and yes, $\pi \in H^2$, but $\bar{\pi}$ isn't.

Comment: Isn't $H^2(\omega)$ the closure of the polynomials in $z$, your $\overline{\pi}$ is a power series in $\overline{z}$ it is not in $H^2(\omega)$

Comment: You still are not addressing my answer.

Comment: The orthogonal projection of $1-\overline{\pi} \in L^2$ on the span of the polynomials is of course in $H^2$. Really your answer is nonsense, make everything concrete you'll see.

Comment: Each of $f_k$ is in $H^2$, are you trying to say that their limit wrt weighted measure is also in $H^2$?

Comment: Sure. And your weighted measure gives the same space as the constant measure

Comment: So you are asserting that if a sequence of functions in $H^2$ converges almost everywhere in nonuniform measure to the limit function, then this limit function is necessarily in $H^2$ as well. I don't think that is correct. If you think it is, please identify an error in my answer.

Comment: For $\omega$ continuous bounded $\ge c > 0$ then $L^2([0,1])$ and $L^2([0,1],\omega)$ have equivalent norms so they are the same Hilbert space, both are the Fourier series with $\ell^2$ coefficients. $H^2$ is the subspace with no negative coefficients, entire functions are dense in them so $H^2=H^2(\omega)$. What do you want more ?

Comment: You are asserting that, but not giving a specific argument why the counterexample is wrong.

Comment: Come on. Asserting what ? What is unclear to you in what I wrote ? I already showed why your answer is nonsense.. For example what is your definition of $H^2$.

Comment: You are asserting that they "have equivalent norms so they are the same Hilbert space". They are not, you are plain wrong about it.

Comment: ??? The inner product are different but the norm is equivalent. If $1/r  \le \omega(x) \le r$ then $r^{-1}\int |f(x)|^2 dx \le \int |f(x)|^2 \omega(x)dx \le r \int |f(x)|^2dx$. That the inner product is different means the orthonormal basis are different, that the norm are equivalent means the map from the orthonormal basis to the other is bounded with bounded inverse.

Comment: You are assuming that the limit of functions in $H^2$ has to be in $H^2$ as well. That is not correct for convergence almost everywhere with respect to nonuniform measure. And you still have not pointed out an error in my answer.

Comment: If it converges in $\omega$-norm it does converge in $L^2$ norm, and $H^2$ is closed in $L^2$ norm... Sorry I'm tired, take some time and come back when everything will be clear to you.

Comment: Difference between $1-\bar{\pi}$ and $f$ is orthogonal in weighted measure to $z^k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, therefore it has zero norm. At the same time, $f\in H^2$, wheras $1-\bar{\pi}$ isn't. I don't think anything is unclear.

Comment: Convergence in $L^2$ norm does imply  convergence in $L^2(\omega)$ norm, but not the other way around.

Comment: Actually, my counterexample is in  error where I asserted that $1-\bar{\pi}-f$ is orthogonal to all powers of z.

Comment: I see why why we have been talking past each other - it's my fault, as I misstated the problem I thinking about - the measure is non-negative rather than positive. Thank you for your time, moving this discussion to chat if you don't mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97642/discussion-between-mikhail-kagalenko-and-reuns).

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the kernel of the measure $\omega$:
$$K = \{g\in L^2: ||g||_\omega=0\}.  $$
When there are points on $T$ where $\omega =0$, the set $K$ is non-empty. If $g\in K$, then $\bar{g} \in K$ as well, so there exists $h\in K$ such that $h\not\in H^2$.

Take any $f\in H^2$, then a sequence $f_k$ that converges to $f$ also converges to $f+h$ almost everywhere with respect to $\omega$-measure. Therefore $f+h\in H^2(\omega)$, while not being in $H^2$.

(Thanks to discussion with reuns, I clarified a misstatement in my original question)